# Once signed up redirected to wrong page

Tags: discussion

Going to another one of the stackexchange sites, when you sign up as a new user (since its your first question) you're taken back to the questions page instead of back to the question you were originally posting.  Can we implement some sort of continuity that allows you to get back to where you were prior?

See also this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/64403/7154

This happened to this user at UX as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I use either the "log in" or "sign up" link from a specific question page on a SE site where I don't yet have an account, I get redirected back to that specific question page - not the questions list.

Comment: Also, probably belongs on Meta.SE as an SE-wide concern, not SO-specific.

Comment: Thats true can a mod move this?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: It's an SO-concern, and thus, per official guidance, it belongs here. It being network-wide and thus also belonging on [meta.SE] is irrelevant. (Mods can migrate it if they so choose. Would be surprised though...)